# why does this button's "click" not work on some regions of the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why does my button's click event not register when the mouse pointer is in the spot shown in the screenshot below? I've created a jsFiddle for you to test it out. Make sure to check your browser's console for feedback.

http://jsfiddle.net/27kRH/

Here is my code, I'm using jQuery

```
var clickCounter = 0;

$('button').click(function(){
    clickCounter++;

    console.log('times clicked: ' + clickCounter);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Its working in jsfiddle as the number is increased in each click.

Comment: @SumanBogati try moving your mouse around a bit, I was able to reproduce his problem on Chrome. There are some odd spots that don't register as a click.

Comment: yeah I reproduced it when I click at bottom and top of button.

Comment: Seems to be related to the `.logInBtn:active` CSS rule. Tried changing the click to a mousedown?

Comment: your button contains a block element `p`

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in Chrome by clicking just above the C in "See [C]onsole"

Comment: Also happens for me if I click on either of the top corners.

Comment: But is it valid HTML? For me not but now i doubt. So, can button tag contains a block element?

Comment: @A.Wolff Maybe not, but that's not the source of the problem... is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Dave explained the problem well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684888/227299) You are moving the element on its active state, moving the element on the active state is causing the mousedown to go to one element and the mouseup to go to another element, therefore, a click is not firing because the OS will only fire a click if the mouseup and mousedown are on the same element.

[I think the best solution is to simplify your code a lot](http://jsfiddle.net/27kRH/17/), and let the button handle the active state, you had styles that were affecting the active look of the button. The following CSS/HTML still has an active look and doesn't move the button from under your mouse, which is a bad idea from a UX perspective.

```
<button id="signUpLogIn-logInBtn" class="logInBtn">
    <img src= "http://s10.postimg.org/z9yrvulut/log_In_Icon.png"/>
     Add One<p class="logInBtnSub">See Console</p>
</button>


.logInBtn {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #c6c6c6; 
    box-shadow: 0 8px #878787;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #402a3e;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
 }

.logInBtn img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
.logInBtnSub{
    font-size: 0.6em;
    color: #878787;     
}
```

Here are a few workarounds

- [Don't use a button, use a div](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/27kRH/11/) (This works everywhere but doesn't use a button, so you don't have an active state)
- [Don't use click, use mouseup](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/27kRH/12/) (This doesn' work at the very top of the button, but works everywhere else)
- [Don't move the button around on its active state](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/27kRH/13/), if you really want the active state to look different, play around with borders/margin padding instead.
- [Use `pointer-events: none` for elements within the button](http://jsfiddle.net/27kRH/14/) This works in the latest browsers I tested IE9, FF, and Chrome (credits to [vals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals))

Comment: Since you are being exhaustive, one last way: set pointer-events: none; on the .logInBtnSub class :-)

Comment: @Juan Mendes +1 for providing different scenarios. I tried the fiddle for the third scenario and button doesnt move when its clicked. can u explain why please?

Comment: @quelquecosa I did explain why. That's what was causing the bug, shifting the element and causing the mouseup to go to a different element. So I removed that feature, but you can still work around it... Isn't the mouseup solution good enough? Val also offered a solution (that I added to the answer) that works in the latest browsers

Answer (score 6):

This issue is that a click is a mousedown + mouseup.  When you click on that area, you are in the portion of a subelement on mousedown, but on mouseup you are in the portion of the parent element, so no element gets the full click.  Not sure what the best way is to fix it, but that is the problem.

```
.logInBtn:active{
    /*top:2.2em;*/
}
```

With that commented out it works.

Comment: You can verify that by doing the mousedown just above the C in "See Console" (where it doesn't catch the click) and then moving the mouse a little (so that the mouseup is on the same element). The workaround is probably just use a mouseup instead.

Comment: Wouldn't the button receive the mouseup and mousedown events because of bubbling and still register a click? I added a body click handler and that's also not firing when it doesn't fire on the button, really weird.

Comment: `onClick` will only trigger when the left mouse button is pressed and released on the same object.  Bubbling won't ever create a new event - it just sends an already existing event up the chain of elements.

Comment: I see, the click event requires that the target of both mouseup and mousedown be the same element.